# EmberJS dynamic routing and configuration

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I use EmberJS v1.0.0-rc.2 and requireJS.
My app structure is kinda like that.

```
- app
- - moduleA
```

My main file:

```
#app/main.js

var App = Ember.Application.create({
    VERSION: '1.0',
    //Log router transitions:
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    AppRouting.call(this);
});

App = AppRoutingExtend(App);

App.initialize();
```

Functions AppRouting() and AppRoutingExtend() could be find in the fellow file:

```
#app/routing.js

function AppRouting() {
    this.resource('root', {path: '/'}, function() {
        this.resource('moduleA', {path: '/'}, function() {
            ModuleARouting.call(this);
        });
    });
}

function AppRoutingExtend(App) {
    var ModuleARouting = ModuleARoutingExtend();

    //Check if ModuleARouting is not empty
    if (!Ember.isEmpty(ModuleARouting)) {
        $.each(ModuleARouting, function(key, value) {
            //Check if key is a string of only letters 
            //  And if value is like Ember.Route.extend({})
            if (typeof key === 'string' && /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(key)
                && value.toString() == '(subclass of Ember.Route)') {
                eval("App.Root" + "ModuleA" + key + "Route = value");
            } else {
                //Throw error
            }
        });
    }

    return App;
}
```

Functions ModuleARouting() & ModuleARoutingExtend() could be find in the follow file:

```
#app/moduleA/routing.js

function ModuleARouting() {
    this.route("contributors", {path: "/"});
    this.resource('aContributor', {path: "/:githubUserName"}, function() {
        this.route("details", {path: "/"});
        this.route("repos", {path: "/repos"});
    });
}

function ModuleARoutingExtend() {
    var routes = {};

    routes['Contributors'] = Ember.Route.extend({
        /*
            Some Code
        */
    });
    routes['AContributor'] = Ember.Route.extend({
        /*
            Some Code
        */
    });
    routes['AContributorDetails'] = Ember.Route.extend({
        /*
            Some Code
        */
    });
    routes['AContributorRepos'] = Ember.Route.extend({
        /*
            Some Code
        */
    });

    return routes;
}
```

I created `AppRouting()` and `ModuleARouting()` to be able to add dynamically some routing path to my application, by adding a new module or remove one. By this way, each module could have its intern structure and `AppRouting()` just merge them.

However, I'm not sure about `ModuleARoutingExtend()` and more specifically `AppRoutingExtend()`. In the last one, I try to modify routes like `App.RootModuleAContributorsRoute`. By the way I don't have information directly which routes have been created by the `ModuleARouting.call(this)`, I cannot know the name of the variable `RootModuleAContributorsRoute`. This is the reason I use eval to be dynamic by getting the 'Contributors' from `ModuleARoutingExtend()` and its value, Ember.Route.extend({/* some code *});

So, my question is: Is there a better way to add dynamically some routes for my application and to get their configuration? And if not, is it still a good way?